# How to modify login page in ngx-admin

Tags: angular9, ngx-admin

I started using the ngx-admin template, and i want to modify the login page.
unfortunately, i couldn't find the login component in the project.
is there any ways to access the login component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you can find detailed instructions here https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/auth/custom-auth-components#setup-auth-container

Keep in mind that @nebular/auth is a module installed with npm, for this reason you cannot find anything in the components pages of project.